# Passing NSURL to UITableViewController

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, ios7

Here my application can open email attachments of a certain type. The only problem is that the method to process the file in the `UITableViewController` is called before the `AppDelegate` method

```
    -(BOOL) application:(UIApplication *)application openURL:(NSURL *)url 
sourceApplication:(NSString *)sourceApplication annotation:(id)annotation
```

So my `NSURL` is always `nil`. Is there any way to programmatically access the delegate after the `view` is loaded?.

Comment: Could you try writing English sentences? Your question is not clear.

Answer (score 0):

You could call your table view's url handling method *from* the app delegate openURL... callback. E.g. by notification (preferred) or by keeping a reference to the table view controller.

To programmatically access your app delegate, use

```
AppDelegate *delegate = (AppDelegate*)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
NSURL *theURL = delegate.url;
```